# ISO 7816-3 for contact card

Tags: protocols, smartcard, iso

i want ask about T=0 transmition protocol can send and receive data in one APDU or no?

example: Reader TX= 90 0A 00 00 05 11 22 33 44 55 and card respond with AA BB CC DD EE FF 11 22 33.

thanks for respond

Answer (score 2):

No, see ISO 7816 part 3. In T=0 the card always responds with 61 xx (if response data exist, of course) and you have to issue a follow-up GET RESPONSE with P3=xx.

In T=1 the response would be sent immediately, but you have to append an LE specification to the command, e.g. LE=0 for up to 255 bytes.

Comment: thanks before sir @guidot, but if i implementetion T=1 in contact card can i get that result sir?

sorry if my english so poor :D

Comment: so i can do it for got like i want with T=1 sir @guidot?
(transmit and receive APDU with data and respond with data + SW1 SW2)
thanks for fast respond :D